# how to use Asynchttp in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

AsynceHTTPClient isn't a non-blocking client?

when i use requests to get response,its work.but i when i use AsyncTTTPClient to post a request,its doesn't work.

```
async def go():
    print('go---------------')
    client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    request = HTTPRequest(url='http://127.0.0.1:8001/api', 
method='GET',)
    r = await client.fetch(request)
    print(r.code, r.body)

async def m(r):
    for _ in range(r):
        await go()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(m(100))
```

when i use AsyncHTTPClient i think the result is like this content

go--- go--- go--- go--- ......

but the real result is

go--- 200 b'' go--- 200 b'' .......

i want a non-blocking requests,so it may send all 100 requests first,and recive the response later, but i got the each response after each reponse .itsn't not-blocking mode
is there something wrong with my code? what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a disadvantage of using coroutines in this case. Because even though the requests are non-blocking, they are not really asynchronous.

You can use [`gen.WaitIterator`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.WaitIterator) to send all the requests at once, truly asynchronously.

As the documentation says:

> If you need to get the result of each future as soon as possible, or if you need the result of some futures even if others produce errors, you can use `WaitIterator`.

It fits your use case perfectly.

`gen.WaitIterator` takes an arbitrary number of futures as arguments and yields the futures as they finish.

However, for this to work, you;ll need to move your `for` loop inside the `go` coroutine. Example:

```
from tornado import gen

async def go(r):
    client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    futures = []

    for _ in range(r):
        print('go----------')
        request = HTTPRequest(url='http://127.0.0.1:8001/api', method='GET',)
        futures.append(client.fetch(request))

    async for result in gen.WaitIterator(*futures):
        print(result.code, result.body)
```

---

As a side note, there's another way to accomplish this—using callbacks. However, `WaitIterator` should be preferred over callbacks. I wrote a [blog post](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2017/10/making-multiple-async-http-requests-using-tornado/) about this sometime ago, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

200 is your status code. It's going like

`go--- r.status_code b'' go--- r.status_code b'' .......`

When you remove your status code from the print is should be printing

`go--- go--- go--- go--- ......`

Comment: yes,i know.
but i means .i want a non-blocking requests,so it may send all 100 requests first,and recive the response later, but i got the each response after each reponse .itsn't not-blocking mode